# Android google support repository 47 update failure

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

Tried with another Android studio version, same error. So the problem is with the support repository update 47. The error is from the log file:

```
2017-04-29 16:55:03,591 [  32839]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Google Repository (extras;google;m2repository) 
2017-04-29 16:55:03,591 [  32839]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger -  
2017-04-29 16:55:03,626 [  32874]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Preparing "Install Google Repository (revision: 47)". 
2017-04-29 16:55:03,650 [  32898]   WARN - ls.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask -  
java.lang.NullPointerException  at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.writeInstallerMetadata(AbstractPackageOperation.java:395)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.prepare(AbstractPackageOperation.java:294)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.preparePackages(InstallTask.java:194)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.run(InstallTask.java:101)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any ideas how to fix? Can't build the projects now

Comment: Weird, if installation fails it must allow you to use, at least, the previous version (46). I've updated a few hours ago to 47 and everything went ok so maybe your solution could be to reinstall your Google Reposiory from your SDK manager (Settings -> Appareance, Behavior -> Android SDk -> SDK Tools -> Support Repository -> Google Repository)

Comment: @MartinRevert Worked fine on my mac, on windows I had to manually remove the repository and do a clean download update, not sure what was the reason in the first place, but I tried several times.

Comment: I have the exact same problem on Windows. I had to go into explorer and blow away the sdk\extras\android\m2repository folder and then install. Even then it failed and had to fall back to the basic installer.